# AVG function changes in different MySQL versions?

Tags: mysql

My webserver is running MySQL client version 5.1.56.

My devserver is running MySQL client version 5.0.7.

This query gives me the same result on both servers:

```
SELECT scenario_user_ratings.userid,
       AVG(scenario_user_ratings.rating)
FROM scenario_user_ratings
GROUP BY scenario_user_ratings.userid
```

both report result:

```
userid  AVG(scenario_user_ratings.rating)
1       3.3659
21      2.8000
22      3.2069
```

but this query yields different results

```
SELECT * FROM ( SELECT scenario_user_ratings.userid,
                       AVG(scenario_user_ratings.rating)
                FROM scenario_user_ratings
                GROUP BY scenario_user_ratings.userid) tabl 
WHERE tabl.userid < 5
```

Dev MySQL v5.0.7 result

```
userid  AVG(scenario_user_ratings.rating)
1       0.9999  <-- average values are always this, regardless
```

Web MySQL v5.1.56 result

```
userid  AVG(scenario_user_ratings.rating)
1       3.3659  <-- correct
```

Apart from the obvious comment of *dev environment should always match production* can someone please explain to me how putting the original query into another query is nuking my `AVG()` values to `0.99999` ? I've narrowed it down to that particular action, and only for this local version of MySQL.

Thank you.

Comment: what you the means by  `DEV MySQL` and `Web MySQL` ?

Comment: What is the datatype of `rating` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see [`here`](http://www.logikdev.com/tag/0-9999-value/)

if you encounter the same problem, you can simply replace the AVG function by the combination `SUM/COUNT.`
For example, the following query:

```
SELECT student_name, AVG(test_score)
FROM student
GROUP BY student_name;
can be replaced by the one below:

SELECT student_name, SUM(test_score)/COUNT(test_score)
FROM student
GROUP BY student_name;
```

Answer (score 1):

If this:

```
SELECT scenario_user_ratings.userid,
       AVG(scenario_user_ratings.rating)
FROM scenario_user_ratings
GROUP BY scenario_user_ratings.userid
HAVING scenario_user_ratings.userid < 5
```

and this:

```
SELECT scenario_user_ratings.userid,
       AVG(scenario_user_ratings.rating)
FROM scenario_user_ratings
WHERE scenario_user_ratings.userid < 5
GROUP BY scenario_user_ratings.userid
```

and this:

```
SELECT * FROM ( SELECT scenario_user_ratings.userid,
                       AVG(scenario_user_ratings.rating)
                FROM scenario_user_ratings
                GROUP BY scenario_user_ratings.userid) tabl 
WHERE tabl.userid < 5
```

do not show the same results in the same data, then I would call it a bug.